# Why array index starts from zero in JAVA ,although it does not support pointers?

Tags: java, arrays

The reasons for array index starting with zero in c can be specified with the concept of pointer and all,but in java there is no pointer . Then what is the exact reason behind array index to be starting with 0 .
If possible do answer which don't have reasons regarding pointers and mathematical simplicity.

Comment: Why does have the first array index of 0 have to have anything to do with pointers? Anyway, this is because it is the way it is, probably because that is the way it was in C/C++. (There are some languages with 1 as the first index, but Java did not 'derive' from that lineage.)

Comment: Why not? Isn't this question yet another, "please guess what the Java developers were thinking" type question? Voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: At the start of a track race what you would put? 0 meters or 1 meter?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor when you're counting apples and lift up the first one, do you say 0 or 1? :P

Comment: When I lift up the first, I say one. Before I say 0.

Comment: Right and what are you holding in your hand when you say zero? It won't be the first apple.

Comment: Well, I would say *0* is the index of the *first element* of an array.. the index is not an ordinal number in Java.

Comment: Implementations will use pointers internally, so avoiding that unneeded offset is always good. Also a lot of languages use 0 based indexing, so using 1 based indexing would be surprising behavior.

Comment: @josefx Unless you're coming from a language with 1-based indexes, of course..

Comment: @user2864740 according to wikipedia it is 33 to 13 in favour of 0 based indexing. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array_system_cross-reference_list)

Comment: @josefx And based on actually language usage (eg. LOC/developer count) it is a *much* higher ratio than that.. however, only 1 out of 10 of the most popular (from current TIOBE) statically-typed programming languages safely/correctly encapsulates 'no value' (known as 'null' in the languages that do not) in the type system (some languages mitigate the usage or alter the behavior, but the point stands). So popular/common is not strictly 'best'.

Comment: @josefx That being said, I find no disagreement with Dijkstra's notes on the topic in Bhargav's answer - but this doesn't mean it couldn't (or isn't or might not be better) done another way.

Answer (score 5):

Probable reason: because C++ uses 0‑based arrays. And C++ uses them because C uses them. And C uses them because in C an array is a pointer to a memory block containing the data for the array. To get to the beginning you added 0 to the memory location. To get to the 2nd item, you added 1 to the memory location, etc etc. The C compiler can use relative indexing in the CPU to make it very fast to find those memory locations.

more specific will be [by Dijkstra regarding exactly this topic.](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF)

Comment: An upvote just for the link..

Comment: @NiravPrajapati thanks buddy but not as good as ur understanding about above topic :P